# Encrypted ArchLinux: unable to find root device

Tags: boot, grub, uuid, cryptsetup

I have a problem with my new installation of ArchLinux with an encrypted partition. I guess I have done the same steps as before and it works on my other machine. The error message I get is:

```
ERROR: device 'UUID=[....]' not found. SKipping fsck.
ERROR: Unable to find root device 'UUID=[...]'.
You are being drpped to recovery shell
```

I have not typed in the UUID, it is the same in both lines.

To fix this I have searched the internet. The first thing I have done was to change the `HOOKS` line in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` to:

```
HOOKS="base udev block autodetect modconf keyboard keymap encrypt filesystems fsck"
```

And the second thing I have done is to `arch-chroot` into it, install linux with `pacman` and doing:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I have also checked the `/etc/fstab` file and this looks also correct and the grub UUID in the `grub.cfg` file looks also correct I have checked this with `blkid`. It is the UUID of `/dev/mapper/vgarch-lvroot`. The same counts for the machine on which it works.

And the third thing I have done was to reinstall grub and redoing the steps but none of this has worked.

Resources: [first](https://superuser.com/questions/769047/unable-to-find-root-device-on-a-fresh-archlinux-install), [second](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148038)

I am looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: You need the `encrypt` hook in your `mkinitcpio.conf` as [per the Arch wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#mkinitcpio)...

Comment: Er, sry I had typed in here the wrong HOOKS line here, I have edited my post now. On my pc I have included encrypt

Comment: So you are working with LVM as well? Post the relevant parts of your grub config and the output of `lsblk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question, I have simply forget to add lvm2 in the HOOKS line of `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`. Now it looks like:

```
HOOKS = "base udev autodetect modconf block keyboard keymap encrypt lvm2 filesystems fsck shutdown"
```